# c# make a ID behind a treeview

Tags: c#

How I can add a ID behind a treeview?
Code:

```
string players = "Name:Peter ID:1 Name:karl ID:2 Name:max ID:3 Name:Nils ID:4";
var user = players.split().Where(a => a.StartWith("Name:")).ToList();
var ID = players.split().Where(a => a.StartWith("ID:")).ToList();
for(int i= 0; i<user.Count(); i++) {
    var pl = user[i].Substring(user[i].IndexOf(":") + 1);
    var plid = ID[i].Substring(ID[i].IndexOf(":") + 1);
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(pl);
}
```

Now I want display the ID in a textbox if select the user

EDIT: 
I have tried

```
treeView1.Tag = plid;
```

but this dont works so..

Comment: Which HTML code? this is c# based

Comment: @FreddyGerogin please tag your GUI Toolkit. Are you using Winforms? C# itself does not have any GUI elements there are plenty of frameworks for GUI......

Comment: I'm using default windowsformapp

Comment: Your Substring call returns the *rest* of the string from index+1. Specify length to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this pattern:

```
for(int i= 0; i<user.Count(); i++) {

    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
    tn.Text = "The name";
    tn.Tag = "The ID";
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh Thanxs I have also tryed the TreeNode but make it wrong D: